# How to Embed iOS Map into UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mapkit, ios6

Do any of you know how to embed the new Map into a nav? We have an app that has the following piece of code--which calls Google Maps to display start and end addresses in a map.

```
NSURL *mapURL = [NSURL URLWithString:some_url_string];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mapURL]];

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.title = @"My Map Display";
[viewController.view addSubview:webview];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

We have the location coordinates which we used to construct the correct url.

The above code pushes the new UIViewController/webview into the navigationController for the current view to allow the user of the app to use the back button to return to our app.

We want to call the new Map API on devices running iOS 6 when user wants the new map. Apple showed the following usage pattern for the new API, MKMapItem:

```
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];
```

However, doing things way has the map rendered over our app--with no obvious way for the user to return to our app from the displayed map. We prefer the map inside a UINavigationController and for the users to be able to use the back button to return from the map display. Do any of you know how we can embed the map inside a navigationController? How can we embed the map generated by the call to [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:]?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a little mistaken with your current solution. Based on what you have said the users are never leaving your app, they are simply seeing Google maps in a UIWebView. The `openMapsWithItems:mapItems:launchOptions:` actually opens the Maps app, and therefore you cannot provide a link back to your app from within the Maps app.

With that said, a couple things to consider.

1. Opening in the Maps app is very useful to a user, they get all the benefits the Maps app provides like turn by turn directions and searching
2. Keeping your users within your app is a very quick and user friendly way to present a location on a map view

So, with those both considered, I personally always vote to do both. Provide a simple map view within your app so that they can quickly take a look at where the location is on the map, but then also provide them the option to open the app within the Maps app so that they can do more if desired.

If you choose this route then what you need to do is look into the MKMapView class, instead of adding your webview as a subview, you will add the MKMapView as a subview and add your annotation to the MKMapView. One common usage pattern is then to allow the user to touch the annotation to bring up a "callout" with a button to open in the maps app.

Comment: The purpose of webView in our implementation is turn-by-turn direction. By the time the user got to this point in our code, they've already gone through a map view to select a particular business. We are trying to let them get a turn-by-turn direction from within the app. This works with url/google. They can use the back button anytime to return to a map view we generated with their selected businesses. We are wondering if there is an equivalent way to achieve the usage pattern with the new map. It sound like you are saying there isn't.

Comment: Right, you cannot access the turn-by-turn feature outside of the Maps app as it is a feature of the Maps app, not the SDK. You certainly could continue what you're doing now, but I'd suggest providing your users the ability to open the address in the Maps app easily.

Comment: It looks like MkMapKit is able to display the new map. I don't know if you work for Apple or not. But, in case you do, I'd like to make a feature request: we'd like to have the capability to display a route between two annotations in a map display.

Comment: @Sunny I don't work for Apple, but you could submit a feature request at bugreporter.apple.com I am sure this is something a lot of people would enjoy seeing.